# Criar gráfico dinâmico usando mysql e Highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, sql, mysqli, highcharts

Pessoal estou tentando criar um gráfico usando o Mysql e Highcharts em um servidor local Xampp. Porem, ao executar o index.php somente o código fonte da página é exibido, não gerando o gráfico.

Segue o abaixo o banco de dados, tabela, conexão com banco de dados Mysql e index.php.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tabela SQL**

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `month` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=118 ;


INSERT INTO `sales` (`id`, `month`, `amount`) VALUES
(24, 'Abr', '15'),
(25, 'Mai', '40'),
(26, 'Jun', '26'),
(27, 'Jul', '31'),
(28, 'Ago', '39'),
(29, 'Set', '25'),
(30, 'Out', '27'),
(31, 'Nov', ' 32'),
(32, 'Dez', NULL);
```

**Banco de Dados**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**database.php**

```html
<?php
 $server      = '<Servcer name>';   // localhost
 $db_user     = '<Database User>';   // root
 $db_password = '<Database Password>';  // 
 $db_name     = '<Database Name>';  // test
 $con = mysqli_connect($server,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);

 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
?>
```

**index.php**

```html
<?php
 require_once('includes/database.php');
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT date_format(purchase_date, '%d-%b-%y') as pDate, sum(total_purchase) as pAmount FROM sales GROUP BY pDate ASC");
 $result = array('day' => array(), 'amount' => array());
 if ($stmt) {
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $day, $amount);
     while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
         $result['day'][] = $day;
         $result['amount'][] = (int)$amount;
     }
     mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

?>
<body>
 <div id="div-chart"></div>
 <script src="includes/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="includes/js/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function () {
      $('#div-chart').highcharts({
          chart: {
              type: 'column'
          },
          title: {
              text: 'Average Purchase'
          },
          subtitle: {
              text: 'Source:'
          },
          xAxis: {
              categories: <?php echo json_encode($result['day']) ?>,
              crosshair: true
          },
          yAxis: {
              min: 0,
              title: {
                  text: 'Amount (Millions)'
              }
          },
          plotOptions: {
              column: {
                  pointPadding: 0.2,
                  borderWidth: 0
              }
          },
          series: [{
              name: 'Purchase',
              data: <?php echo json_encode($result['amount']) ?>
          }]
      });
  });
 </script>
</body>
```

**Resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não está abrindo a página no servidor...

Tem que colocar as páginas dentro de uma pasta no `htdoc` do xampp e abrir o localhost/nome_da_pasta para funcionar.

Comment: Já resolvi este problema Eduardo um dos erros estava em não chamar meu arquivo php no servidor.